# spring-batch header/footer/trailer of groups

Tags: spring-batch

I've to generate a file that contains monetary transactions of different merchants in something like following format:

```
FILE_HEADER
       MERCHANT_AND_CURRENCY_HEADER
         TRANSACTION_WITH_AMOUNT_AND_SAME_CURRENCY_INDICATED_IN_HEADER
       MERCHANT_FOOTER_WITH_COUNTER_AND_TOTAL_AMOUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS_FOR_CURRENT_CURRENCY
       MERCHANT_AND_CURRENCY_HEADER
         TRANSACTION_WITH_AMOUNT_AND_SAME_CURRENCY_INDICATED_IN_HEADER
       MERCHANT_FOOTER_WITH_COUNTER_AND_TOTAL_AMOUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS_FOR_CURRENT_CURRENCY
       MERCHANT_AND_CURRENCY_HEADER
         TRANSACTION_WITH_AMOUNT_AND_SAME_CURRENCY_INDICATED_IN_HEADER
       MERCHANT_FOOTER_WITH_COUNTER_AND_TOTAL_AMOUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS_FOR_CURRENT_CURRENCY
FILE_FOOTER
```

Nowadays my solution is picking up from database all transactions ordered by merchant and currency and checking for each item if the currency and merchant of the current transaction are equal to the previous one and if those fields are different I'm appending to the file the footer of previous group and the header of the current group.
Is there in spring-batch any other approach to solve this cases? I was thinking to start using nested jobs but I'm not sure I that is the right way.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a logical output item in your case could be:

```
MERCHANT_AND_CURRENCY_HEADER
   TRANSACTION_WITH_AMOUNT_AND_SAME_CURRENCY_INDICATED_IN_HEADER
MERCHANT_FOOTER_WITH_COUNTER_AND_TOTAL_AMOUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS_FOR_CURRENT_CURRENCY
```

So what you can do is for example:

- Use the `FlatFileHeaderCallback` and `FlatFileFooterCallback` to write `FILE_HEADER` and `FILE_FOOTER` globally
- Define a logical item such that when written it produces the previous 3 lines

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In fact, I'm using callbacks for global header and footer and those work as expected. But in my example I was not clear about the structure. There is no only one item between group header/footer, it can contain a number of variable items like following
`
MERCHANT_AND_CURRENCY_HEADER
   TRANSACTION1_WITH_AMOUNT_AND_SAME_CURRENCY_INDICATED_IN_HEADER
TRANSACTION2_WITH_AMOUNT_AND_SAME_CURRENCY_INDICATED_IN_HEADER
TRANSACTIONn_WITH_AMOUNT_AND_SAME_CURRENCY_INDICATED_IN_HEADER
MERCHANT_FOOTER_WITH_COUNTER_AND_TOTAL_AMOUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS_FOR_CURRENT_CURRENCY
`

Comment: Yes I see. My point is that you create an object that encapsulates a group of transactions and use that aggregate object as input item to the writer.

Comment: Point me in the rigth direction if I'm wrong, what I understand is that I can have an item with a list of all transactions related to a group and I have to apply a logic to write for that item the header, the body and the footer once at a  time? 
Couldn't I have any performance issue having several items in memory related to a group before to write that agreggated item?

Comment: Correct. In regards to performance, It depends on how many transactions could belong to the same group. I suggest to do a pre analysis of your data and see if this could have a potential performance issue.